# No internet (wireless nor wired) on HP 6735b after upgrade to 12.10

Tags: wireless

So I've got a HP 6735b laptop.

When I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on it, I didn't have any wireless. After I downloaded the drivers via wired connection everything worked fine.

Now I've upgraded to 12.10 and I can connect to wireless, but it doesn't allow me to browse. I can also connect to wired internet, but that as well doesn't allow me to browse or do any update, install, upgrade.

I checked proxy settings and they are off.
What is strange though, is that pinging to google.be gives: 
"ping: unknown host google.be"

but pinging to 8.8.8.8 works as it should
"PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data."

pinging 8.8.8.8 (google DNS) works without dropping a package or whatsoever.

I also tried it on another network and that doesn't work either.

Advice on how to fix?

---

FIXED METHOD BELOW

---

Thx to maggotbrain and @spruyttej (on twitter) I was able to browse again.

> Can you edit the file /etc/resolv.conf, adding the line nameserver 8.8.8.8 to it and browse from your wired connection? – maggotbrain

The file maggotbrain talked about did not exist. So I did:

```
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

and then added `nameserver 8.8.8.8` to the file.

I rebooted and my internet was working. Though I wasn't certain whether this was a fix or a workaround.

on twitter @spruyttej told me to run:

```
sudo apt-get install resolvconf; sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf;
```

This rewrote the `/etc/resolv.conf` file.

I'm now browsing happily. Thx guys!

Comment: Can you edit the file `/etc/resolv.conf`, adding the line `nameserver 8.8.8.8` to it and browse from your wired connection?

Comment: File didn't exist, adding that nameserver does make it work. Can I use this as a "fix" or is it just a workaround that I should only use temporary?

Comment: it works.. I've written an answer but can't post it  (new account, can't post answer in first 8 hours)

Comment: I guess you can use this as a permanent fix, but the problem here is that you do not have proper DNS addresses: either obtained from your router/ISP if you are using DHCP, or set explicitly if static DNSes are required. Have a look at whether you can fix this with Network Connections.

Comment: @user114254 I would only consider that a temporary fix. You may have some other problems with your Network Manager and possibly the dnsmasq-base before you can get your wireless working. Your /etc/resolv.conf file _should_ have been already present with a warning not to edit it.

Comment: You added the solution to your question but you can also post it as an answer and accept that. That way users will know that this question has already been satisfactorily answered.

Answer (score 0):

As reported in bug #1000244 there are various circumstances under which the needed symbolic link `/etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` fails to get created or gets deleted by misbehaving software. This can result in host name resolving failures.

As has already been mentioned, the solution is to ensure that resolvconf is installed correctly.  The following commands

```
sudo apt-get install resolvconf
sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf
```

should ensure this.